Show that the smallest such Grothendieck topology is the open cover topology
This is an exercise in Maclane-Moerdijk (III.6.(b)). Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a small category, and $S_\alpha$ any collection of sieves on objects $C_\alpha$. It is easy to show that there is a smallest Grothendieck topology such that these sieves become covers. The goal is to show this: on the category of smooth manifolds $\mathbf{M}$, the open cover topology (i.e. a basis for the Grothendieck topology on each manifold $M$ consists of the families of open embeddings $\{f_i: U_i \to M\}$ such that $\bigcup_i f(U_i) = M$) is the smallest Grothendieck topology such that the sieves generated by $\{(-\infty, 1), (-1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\{(-n, n) \to \mathbb{R}: n > 0\}$ cover $\mathbb{R}$.
It is easy to show that if the result is proven for $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. if the topology generated on $\mathbf{M}$ is such that, on $\mathbb{R}$, every sieve generated by an open covering is indeed a cover), then we have the result for all $\mathbb{R}^n$ and by Whitney embedding, the result for all manifolds $M$ as well. However, I'm struggling to show this for $\mathbb{R}$. How would I do this?

Can you prove it for the case of two open sets, i.e. if $U \cup V = M$ then ${ U \hookrightarrow M, V \hookrightarrow M }$ is in that smallest Grothendieck topology?  (Assuming "smooth manifolds" are paracompact by definition, and therefore "smoothly completely normal"...)

@DanielSchepler Thank you for the hint—I see now that after proving the case for two, we can use induction to get the result for all finite covers then conclude by paracompactness.

Is the same strategy viable for the second sieve?

I'd imagine the second generator could be useful for passing from finite covers to countable covers.  If you can let $V_n := U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_n$, and then find a function $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}((-n, n)) = V_n$, then...
